# Trees swaying in the wind using Tilemap

Tags: unity, tilemap

I am working on a top-down, tile-based game (think 2D RPG). However, I would like to have trees that sway in the wind and shake a little if the player bumps into them!

How should I approach this? Is it achievable with trees that are composed of tiles and part of a tilemap?

Or should I exclude my trees from the tilemap and turn them into game objects instead?

If I were to turn them into separate game objects, would I then manually tweak their rotation/position to achieve the sway and shake, or is there some form of shader I can use?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.tilemap.extras@1.6/manual/AnimatedTile.html if this is enough for your need

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with Animated Tiles and the 2D Extras Package. But with those, I would need to create sprite animations and then play them on the events. My trees also are more than a single tile high and wide, so that's a problem. My question is if there is a way to achieve this programmatically, without having to create additional tree sprite frames, and including more/random variety of the animation?

Comment: If you want to go with a shader, there are some easy ways how to achieve the effect. What is best for you depends as well how your game works. YouTube has more than one shader solution if you want to do it that way. https://youtu.be/aKzUsxLJ4SU And of course you can have different sized tiles in your game. Your tree trunk could be 2x1 with a 3x3 secondary animated crown

Comment: Thanks, will the shader from the video be suitable for pixel art?

Comment: Just try it out. The whole video is 11min, just add a single tree and see if it works for your game. But it should be suitable if you don't go crazy on the numbers. If the shader is 80% to your liking, just edit your question with the shader and how you would like to look it to get specific help

Comment: I should add, when I say "sway", what I mean is the crown rotating with the pivot set to the top of the stem.

Comment: That detail belongs in your question. Try including a screenshot of your trees, or a mock-up of what you want a swaying frame to look like.